# Better way to organize Rails initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, initialization, environment

in my current Rails project I ended up with a lot of environment-specific initializers, for example my `carrierwave.rb`:

For development I use something like:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.cache_dir = Rails.root.join('tmp', 'carrierwave')
  config.storage = :file
end
```

For production I use S3 through `fog`:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.cache_dir = Rails.root.join('tmp', 'carrierwave')
  config.storage = :fog

  config.fog_public  = false
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:     '...',
    aws_secret_access_key: '...'  
  }
end
```

I don't want to use lots of `Rails.env.development?` calls to switch between the configs, and I don't want to store this initializers inside my `environment/*.rb` files. Is there a way, for example to create a directory for each of my environments under the `initializers` directory?

```
initializers
├── development
│   └── carrierwave.rb
├── production
│   └── carrierwave.rb
└── test
    └── carrierwave.rb
```

The problem according to the Rails guides is following:

> You can use subfolders to organize your initializers if you like, because Rails will look into the whole file hierarchy from the initializers folder on down.

Answer (score 3):

Put your environment specific initializers under `/config/environments/initializers/[env]` for example `/config/environments/initializers/development` and add something like this to `config/application.rb`:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Load environment specific initializers from "config/environments/initializers/[current_env]".
    initializer 'load_environment_initializers', after: :load_config_initializers do |app|
      Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'environments', 'initializers', Rails.env.to_s, '**', '*.rb')].each {|file| require file }
    end

    ...

 end
end
```

It will require (load) all files from `/config/environments/initializers/[env]` and its subdirectories just after it has finished loading all regular initializers.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to move into into another directory mate, everything in the initializers folder will get included at boot time.

If you put the above instead into say..

rails_root/config/env_init_files/development

rails_root/config/env_init_files/production

Then you could do something like this..

```
#at the end of your environment.rb        
Dir["#{Rails.root}/config/env_init_files/#{Rails.env}/**/*"].each { |initializer| require initializer }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dotenv gem and use environment variables to change the config across environemnts.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Capistrano recipe that does this.  Credentials are stored outside the repo (in a folder called /var/secure/) and are symlinked into config/initializers/ on deployment.

```
namespace :local do
  desc "Symlink all files in /var/secure into config/initializers.  This is how we get production keys into our apps without hard-coding them.  If they're production-only, great.  If there are development and production credentials, put the development credentials in the repo, and they will be overwritten during deploy."
  task :symlink_secure_initializers, :roles => [:app,:api] do
    run "for l in `ls /var/secure/*.rb`; do 
           rm -f #{release_path}/config/initializers/$(basename $l)
           ln -s /var/secure/$(basename $l) #{release_path}/config/initializers/$(basename $l)
         done"
  end
end

after "deploy:update_code", "local:symlink_secure_initializers"
```